# Split html table, odd columns to even

Tags: html, html-table

I would like a single `<table>` tag to render like this:

```
+_____+_____+_____+
|     |     |     |
+_____+_____+_____+
|     |     |     |
+_____+_____+_____+
|                 |
+________+________+
|        |        |
+________+________+
|        |        |
+________+________+
```

Possible? I am lost on this one. I've been tableless for a long time. Documentation on changing the column numbers half way through is not clear. I know it could be done with `col-span` if the shift in columns was even, but how to go from odd to even?

Comment: He demostrated a good understanding of the question and showed what is limiting him from getting to the solution. I don't think it should be closed.

Comment: @william.eyidi yeah, SO has some bad justifications for some of these things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Explanation**

Provide a colspan of two for those td's that only require one space, and then you'll be able to use 3 (which is actually 1.5) as the colspan for the other row. Maybe this isn't the best solution, but it's the first that I came up with.

The example only has two of the 3 types of rows you had in your example, but to add the whole width cell, just add a colspan of 6.

**Code**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan=2></td>
        <td colspan=2></td>
        <td colspan=2></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan=3></td>
        <td colspan=3></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[image]

**The [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pgwns/)**

Comment: Perfect, it just sums to multiply them by 2 has the value of colspan can only be integers.

Answer (score 2):

Find the smallest common divisor, in this case 6, and set a colspan on each cell to divide that number by the number of cells in the row.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="6"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3"></td>
        <td colspan="3"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/S5K8p/